# Parentheses messing up validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I have the following validation:

```
  validates_format_of :title, 
                  :with => /^[A-Z0-9 áàâäãçéèêëíìîïñóòôøöõúùûüý'-.]*$/i,  
                  :message => "must contain only letters, numbers, dashes, periods, and single quotes"
```

This works most of the time, but when a title contains an open and closed parentheses, it passes.  Anyone know how to get around this or maybe there is something wrong with my validation regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your regular expression you have `'-.`

This means that you want to allow all characters between (and including) the apostrophe and the period just like you did at the beginning of the regular expression with A-Z and 0-9.

The expression `/['-.]/` allows all these characters: `'()*+,-.`

Inside the [], you need to escape the - character. I think that this will work the way you are hoping:

```
/^[A-Z0-9 áàâäãçéèêëíìîïñóòôøöõúùûüý'\-.]*$/i
```

PS. You don't have to escape the . inside the square brackets []